# How to remove commits like these

Tags: git

I have this situation:

```
                    B     C     D
              /-----*-----*-----*
-*---*---*---*---*---* branch A
 A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
```

Commits B, C, D do not belong to any branch. If I run my fancy `git lg` it doesn't show any branch labels near them (it does for master, origin/master, HEAD, topic branches, etc). If I checkout them I move to "detached head" state (this is expected, because the only way I can checkout them is using sha1). How do I remove them?

Things I tried so far:

1. Checkout commit D and run `git reset HEAD~3 --hard`, HEAD pointer moves to A4, but commits are still here.
2. Manually running `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`, followed by `git gc --prune=now`, commits are still here.

What is happening and how do I remove these commits?

Edit: 39d9480 is one of the problematic commits. Tried experimenting with merge-base, got this output:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor 39d9480 master; echo $?
0
git merge-base --is-ancestor master 39d9480; echo $?
1
```

I don't see this commit when trying to rebase.

Comment: If you've done the reflog expiry and gc, they would normally be gone at this point, suggesting there's *something* still referring to them (such as the `refs/originals/` namespace that `git filter-branch` leaves behind).  What does your `git lg` alias expand to?

Comment: `git log --graph --oneline --decorate`

Comment: Going to check out refs/originals.

Comment: Ah, add `--all` to bring in every reference under `refs/` (such as `refs/stash` and the aforementioned `refs/originals/` space).

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that option, it is in alias as well, thats how I see them.

Comment: try `git branch -a --contains D` to find references which hold them

Answer (score 0):

The `git branch` command scans only local and remote branches. This script will show any kind of reference which contains the commit with given *hash*:

`git for-each-ref -s --format 'if git merge-base --is-ancestor`*hash*`%(refname); then printf "%s\n" %(refname); else :; fi;'|/bin/sh -`

Comment: Tried using it, no output.

Answer (score -1):

For what I know, you can't remove commits by yourself. They will disappear after some times, thanks to Git. But they won't interfer with your work :)

Comment: Yeah, they won't interfer, but I would like to understand what happened.

Comment: I think Git allows you to recover your work if you did some crap ... but it's just a theory. I can't help you, I haven't found the answer yet

Comment: Yes, it has powerful tools to recover work like `git reflog`, but this situation is opposite. I want to LOSE these commits from history, but can't find a way to remove them.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this creating a branch, rebasing it to nothing, and deleting it:

```
git checkout D_HASH
git checkout -b disposable
git rebase -i HEAD~4
[ interactively delete commits from branch only -- do NOT delete A4 ]
git branch -D disposable
```

Comment: I tried this, branch is deleted but commits are there. As @torek suggested above it looks something else refers to these commits.